# On finding sites with (difficult) practice problems

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, problem-solving

I am a HS junior taking Calculus BC and have probably one of the most difficult teachers to ever exist ever. Her first test was tear-stimulant and she offers absolutely no practice sheets or problems, other than the relatively simplistic examples she gives in class.

Which leads me to my next point: Are there any particular websites with repositories of these difficult problems? The majority of sites only explain basic concepts and simple problems to apply them to, which is useless for me.  If you know of any very challenging Precalc/Calc websites( OR BOOKS) , please link them here.

Thanks!

(Mods and experienced users: I am still very new to StackExchange in general. Sorry if this question is in the wrong community, and please redirect the question to the correct one if it is.)

EDIT: My little brother is a sophomore in Precalculus and would like the same thing- any other links?

Comment: http://www.free-test-online.com/ap/ap_bc_mc.htm

Comment: Some of the suggestions given at [Extremely “hard” books (or handouts) for undergrad studies](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/extremely-hard-books-or-handouts-for-undergrad-studies) might be helpful. Note that the question actually asked about calculus and analysis, despite the more general question in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sites, try Google "math problem books". For example, [this link](http://www.mathpropress.com/mathBooks/), and also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306828/list-of-problem-books-in-undergraduate-and-graduate-mathematics) Math.SE post.

For calculus, I personally recommend [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0846407612) by Demidovich. It is very popular in my country.

Comment: Where is Demidovich popular? I'd like to read it too.

Comment: I am from China, where many math majored freshmen will try this book. Some will do every problem in it. Although I did not try it out, because I am not math majored, I realize that many techniques in this book quite useful in physics.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to a book selling for only 2000 dollars. Is there a cheaper version?? Lol @taper

Comment: @KMoy Oh. I just Google for it and find this link. Actually, this book is very old and already available in PDF. You can find it [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=Problems+in+mathematical+analysis+Demidovich&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def).

Comment: Thanks for finding the torrent!