# Best books for self study with challenging exercises and solutions?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm looking for books at the undergraduate, possibly early graduate level in more or less any topic but I'm really looking for books with a certain structure that I find the best for self study.

Namely, something with frequently interspersed , well-thought out, exercises preferably with solutions. I find it best to learn through exercises and like a mix of easy drill exercises to quickly grasp a new concept followed by harder exercises to explore the theory (maybe towards the end of a chapter).

Are there any books like this? I know that exercises tend to be more and more vague and self directed as the level of the subject gets harder but if anyone knows any books like this it would be great. Some nice topics would be measure theory, probability, (measure theoretic probability), geometry, algebra, complex analysis. Stochastic's?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306828/list-of-problem-books-in-undergraduate-and-graduate-mathematics/306860#306860

Comment: Maybe the Schaum's Outline series.

Comment: I am going through Blitzstein and Hwang's "Introduction to Probability" and it is great. There are hundreds of problems and many of them have solutions that can be found online at the book's website.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement that there should be solutions seriously restricts the number of choices.

Here are a couple of books I can think of.

*Linear Algebra Problem Book* by Halmos.

*Elementary Topology: Problem Textbook* by Viro, Ivanov, Netsvetaev, Kharlamov.